# Не работает движение персонажа в unity2d, анимация при этом проигрывается

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация, 2d

Посмотрите, пожалуйста, что не так? Root motion не реагирует, скрипт на персонаже, аниматор настроен, граунды расставлены. не вижу что не так// зы прыжок отрабатывает как надо

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

public enum ProjectAxis {onlyX = 0, xAndY = 1};
public ProjectAxis projectAxis = ProjectAxis.onlyX;
public float speed = 150;
public float addForce = 7;
public KeyCode leftButton = KeyCode.Keypad4;
public KeyCode rightButton = KeyCode.Keypad6;
public KeyCode upButton = KeyCode.Keypad8;
public KeyCode downButton = KeyCode.Keypad5;
public KeyCode addForceButton = KeyCode.Space;
private bool isFacingRight = true;
private Vector3 direction;
private float vertical;
public float horizontal;
private Rigidbody2D body;
private bool jump;
private Animator anim;


void Start () 
{
    body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    body.freezeRotation = true;
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

    if(projectAxis == ProjectAxis.xAndY) 
    {
        body.gravityScale = 0;
        body.drag = 10;
    }
}

void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D coll) 
{
    if(coll.transform.tag == "Ground")
    {
        body.drag = 10;
        jump = true;
    }
}

void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D coll) 
{
    if(coll.transform.tag == "Ground")
    {
        body.drag = 0;
        jump = false;
    }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    body.AddForce(direction * body.mass * speed);

    if(Mathf.Abs(body.velocity.x) > speed/100f)
    {
        body.velocity = new Vector2(Mathf.Sign(body.velocity.x) * speed/100f, body.velocity.y);
    }

    if(projectAxis == ProjectAxis.xAndY)
    {
        if(Mathf.Abs(body.velocity.y) > speed/100f)
        {
            body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x, Mathf.Sign(body.velocity.y) * speed/100f);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(addForceButton) && jump)
        {
            body.velocity = new Vector2(0, addForce);
        }
    }
}

void Flip()
{
    if(projectAxis == ProjectAxis.onlyX)
    {
        isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }
}

void Update () 
{
    
    if(Input.GetKey(upButton)) vertical = 1;
    else if(Input.GetKey(downButton)) vertical = -1; else vertical = 0;

    if(Input.GetKey(leftButton)) horizontal = -1;
    else if(Input.GetKey(rightButton)) horizontal = 1; else horizontal = 0;

    if(projectAxis == ProjectAxis.onlyX) 
    {
        direction = new Vector2(horizontal, 0); 
    }
    else 
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(addForceButton)) speed += addForce; else if(Input.GetKeyUp(addForceButton)) speed -= addForce;
        direction = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(leftButton) || Input.GetKey(rightButton))
    {
        anim.SetBool("isWalk", true);
    }
    else
    {
        anim.SetBool("isWalk", false);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(upButton))
    {
        anim.SetBool("isJump", true);
    }
    else 
    {
        anim.SetBool("isJump", false);
    }

    if(horizontal > 0 && !isFacingRight) Flip(); else if(horizontal < 0 && isFacingRight) Flip();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала раздели суп от мух, у тебя в одном классе куча не связанных ответственностей: управление, передвижение, анимация... все нужно разделить.

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(UnitMovement))]
public class PlayerInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string _moveAxis = "Horizontal";
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode _jumpKey = KeyCode.Space;
    private UnitMovement _target;

    private void Start ()
    {
        _target = GetComponent<UnitMovement>();
    }

    private void Update ()
    {
        _target.MoveInput = Input.GetAxis(_moveAxis);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(_jumpKey);)
            _target.TryJump();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class GroundCheck : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [SerializeField] private float _radius;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask _mask;

    public bool OnGround { get; private set; }

    private void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        OnGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(transform.position, _radius, _mask);
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected ()
    {
        Gizmos.DrawSphere(transform.position, _radius);
    }
}
```

---

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class UnitMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _moveSpeed = 150;
    [SerializeField] private float _jumpForce = 7;
    [Space]
    [SerializeField] private GroundCheck _ground;
    private Rigidbody2D _body;

    public float MoveInput { get; set; }
    public bool OnGround => _ground.OnGround;

    private void Start ()
    {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        _body.velocity = new Vector2(_moveSpeed*MoveInput, _body.velocity.y);
    }

    public void TryJump ()
    {
        if (_ground.OnGround)
            _body.velocity = new Vector2(0, _jumpForce);
    }
}
```

---

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(UnitMovement), typeof(Animator))]
public class UnitSkin : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private Animator _animator;
    private UnitMovement _unit;

    // ...
}
```

Тогда ты хоть сможешь дебащить и проверить работаспособность каждой сущьности в отдельности, не ломая ВСЕ.

Другие персонади и враги вряд ли двигаются как-то иначе, код должен быть тот-же самый.